# Dafny fails to prove max element in integer array

Tags: specifications, dafny, loop-invariant

I'm trying to prove a simple program in Dafny that finds the maximum element of an integer array. **Dafny succeeds** in a few seconds proving the program below. When I **remove the comments** from the last two `ensures` specifications, Dafny fires error messages saying that

```
a postcondition might not hold on this return path
```

This is probably caused by the fact that `index` is guaranteed to be `<= a.Length`. However, `max_index < a.Length` is correct, and I'm having a hard time proving it. I tried writing a nested invariant in the `if` statement, but Dafny rejected that syntax. Any possible solution?
Here is my code:

```
method FindMax(a: array<int>) returns (max: int, max_index : int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] <= max
    ensures 0 <= max_index
    // ensures max_index < a.Length
    // ensures a[max_index] == max
{
    max := 0;
    var index := 0;
    max_index := 0;
    while index < a.Length
        invariant 0 <= index <= a.Length
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < index ==> a[k] <= max
    {
        if (max  < a[index])
            // invariant 0 <= index < a.Length
        {
            max := a[index];
            max_index := index;
        }
        index := index + 1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my loop invariants needed more careful planning. Here is the correct version:

```
method FindMax(a: array<int>) returns (max: int, max_index : int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] <= max
    ensures 0 <= max_index
    ensures max_index < a.Length
    ensures a[max_index] == max
{
    var index := 0;
    max_index := 0;
    max := a[max_index];
    while index < a.Length
        invariant max_index < a.Length
        invariant 0 <= index <= a.Length
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < index ==> a[k] <= max
        invariant a[max_index] == max
    {
        if (max  < a[index])
        {
            max := a[index];
            max_index := index;
        }
        index := index + 1;
     }
}
```

And it takes Dafny a little over than 10 seconds to prove.